# How to read volume value from mp3 file in python and ffmpeg or similar

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to read volume value from mp3 file (filename.mp3) and not by recording the audio file as in this example :

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np

def print_sound(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    print (int(volume_norm))

with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
    sd.sleep(10000)
```

output :

```
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
17
24
8
5
15
18
16
6
2
3
5
10
8
5
1
0
0
2
4
3
1
0
0
0
1
3
4
2
0
0
2
2
4
4
3
0
0
2
2
5
3
0
0
0
0
3
3
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
4
3
3
7
13
4
4
3
5
6
3
2
3
3
4
6
6
6
4
3
3
2
3
6
6
8
12
15
1
0
0
1
12
19
2
4
3
6
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
5
0
0
2
3
0
0
0
0
0
5
5
17
4
6
3
4
5
16
10
7
31
5
1
0
0
0
0
3
3
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
7
0
2
5
20
5
6
5
29
12
4
7
2
0
1
5
13
51
5
9
44
7
3
3
4
4
4
1
1
1
1
110
71
0
0
48
23
28
4
0
0
0
0
0
74
53
37
29
26
15
17
14
7
5
5
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
7
7
6
6
6
6
6
6
4
53
47
18
13
9
8
8
7
5
4
4
4
4
5
6
6
6
5
4
3
3
3
2
3
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
7
7
8
7
18
8
2
2
4
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

install: `pip install ffmpegio`

then the following code should do what you want:

```py
import ffmpegio
import numpy as np

nframes=16 # read 16 frames at a time

with ffmpegio.open(mp3file, 'ra', blocksize=nframes, sample_fmt='dbl') as file:
    for i, indata in enumerate(file):
        volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
        n0 = i*indata # starting sample index
        t = np.range(n0,n0+volume_norm.shape[0])/file.sample_rate       
        print (int(volume_norm))
```

`sample_fmt='dbl'` argument makes `indata` to be `float` data type. If you want to keep the original sample type, remove the argument.

I'm the dev of [ffmpegio](https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/) library. Let me know if you encounter any issues, and I'll fix'em asap.

edit: Fixed `frames` -> `indata`

Comment: Thank you very much sir @kesh this is what i need, but can you please guide me how i can have time with every volumes values

Comment: Modified code to compute the time vector associated with the samples

Comment: @kesh, thanks for sharing. when running the code, it give "NameError: name 'frames' is not defined". can you please advise? thank you.

Comment: @MarkK - sorry to be late replying. There was a typo. (`frames` should've read `indata`) Post has been fixed

Comment: @kesh, thank you for the fix. But it still says "NameError: name 'frames' is not defined" for this line "with ffmpegio.open(mp3file, 'ra', blocksize=frames, sample_fmt='dbl') as file:"

Comment: Oops, my bad. That argument should be an integer to specify how many video frames you want to read each iteration. The edited code reads 16 frames/iteration.